# Can this frost free garden faucet leak be fixed?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I have a garden faucet that appears to leak through the packing nut but it is hard to tell. I have a video that shows the leak.

https://youtu.be/-BHnZI1TVb8

When I slowly open the faucet, the leak gradually increases but then almost stops when the faucet is fully opened. Is the packing nut bad or is it something else? Can a new packing nut fix this?

Comment: It is definitely a leak in the area where traditional "stuffing box" valves have packing. The problem is that yours is a more modern design and may not have traditional packing material, more likely an o-ring and maybe some friction washers.

I wish your video showed the end of the knob, does it have a screw holding it on? Take off the knob and inspect the stem retention/sealing facilities. Only disassembly will reveal the repair path. P.S.- turn off the water first! P.S.S.- when I said *modern* I meant cheap/disposable

Comment: There is a screw in front of the valve. I took this off and looked inside. The washer seemed fine and the packing nut (plastic) was tightened. That helped it from leaking when the faucet is on full, but didn't fix the leak in its entirety.

Comment: If you turn the water off and remove the packing nut, you will likely find some washers that you might be able to replace. There is probably a rubber o-ring there.

Comment: Keep in mind that the actual valve is located several inches or a foot down  inside the tube, The knob turns a rod that connects to a valve deep inside the house. It does seem in your case the outer seals are the problem however.

Comment: I agree with most of the above post. The fix may be as simple as as tighting the packing nut. At worst some Gortex rope wrapped around the shaft and then the packing nut tightened. The easy way would be a worn rubber washer needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was the bibb washer at the end of the stem. I ended up buying a repair kit and followed this video. https://youtu.be/JOsmL2XtyMw

The kit is a Wall Hydrant Complete Service Kit that I bought at Home Depot for $20. 
http://thd.co/1WcIbrP

It wasn't too bad. Hardest part was removing the rusted screw in front of the knob. I had to use some PB Blaster and a ratchet to grip the hex screw head. Once I got that off, I just followed the video. The faucet is drop free now!

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find parts and get it fixed! The bibb washer would have nothing to do with it though, it was probably other things you did when you had it apart.Cheers!